# How to solve surface area problem?

Tags: calculus

A sphere balloon is inflated at 5 cubic centimeters per second. How fast is the surface area increasing when the radius is 25 centimeters?

I don't understand the goal of the problem. I thought related rate problems were supposed to be solved through differentiation, but there's nothing in the problem to differentiate. How can it be solved?

Comment: $\frac{\Delta \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3}{\Delta t}=5cm$...

Comment: This question was asked 2 years ago, but I provide this comment for current readers. You are given a derivative, the rate of change of volume of the sphere.  You are asked to find a derivative, namely the rate of change in surface area.  So, it turns out that you will be differentiating both the equations for surface area and volume of a sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for $\frac{dA}{dt}=\frac{dA}{dr}\cdot  \frac{dr}{dV}\cdot  \frac{dV}{dt}$

The volume is $V(r)=\frac{4}{3}\pi \cdot r^3$. Differentiating $V(r)$ w.r.t $r$.

$\frac{dV}{dr}=4\pi r^2$. This is equal to the surface of the balloon (A).

$A=\frac{dV}{dr}\Rightarrow \frac1A=\frac{dr}{dV}\Rightarrow \frac1{4\pi r^2}=\frac{dr}{dV}$

And $\frac{dA}{dr}=8\pi r$

Therefore $\frac{dA}{dr}\cdot \frac{dr}{dV}=\frac{8\pi r}{4\pi r^2}=\frac2r$

The values of $\frac{dV}{dt}$ and $r$ are given.

Answer (score 1):

hint...You are looking for $\frac {dA}{dt}$ when $r=25$. For the sphere, $V=\frac 43\pi r^3$ and $A=4\pi r^2$. You are given $\frac{dV}{dt}=5$.

Therefore using the Chain Rule,$$\frac{dA}{dt}=\frac{dA}{dr}\times \frac{dr}{dV}\times \frac{dV}{dt}$$